# What's the best practice to convert an array of String to an array of doubles (primitive type)

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose I have an array of String, `variables`, how can I parse it into another array of double, `converted`, in an effective way?

```
String[] variables = {"1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5"};

double[] converted;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
String[] variables = { "1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5" };
double[] result = new double[variables.length];
for(int i = 0; i < variables.length; i++){
    result[i]=Double.parseDouble(variables[i]);
}
```

Or use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/):

```
final String[] variables = { "1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5" };
double[] result = Doubles.toArray(Collections2.transform(
    Arrays.asList(variables),
    new Function<String, Double>(){

        @Override
        public Double apply(final String input){
            return Double.valueOf(input);
        }
    }));
```

But that doesn't make life much simpler in this case, does it?

Comment: now  what if the string variables has empty "" instead of doubles or both

Comment: @Suresh well then we would have to build in some checks, but that was not part of the question

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] variables = {"1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5"};

double[] converted = new double[variables.length];

int i = 0;

for (String each : variables)
    converted[i++] = Double.parseDouble(each);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(converted));
```